# Get an Id from a connected table using UnitOfWork

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I've got a many to many relationship between actors and events,
I want to remove an event, I get the `eventId` in the function,
how do I find the connected players to remove them as well?

```cs
public ActionResult Delete(int id)
{
    bool isSuccess = false;
    try
    {
        using (var unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork(new ht1Entities()))
        {
            Event eventObj = unitOfWork.Events.Get(id);
            var actors = unitOfWork.Actors.Find(x=>x.Events.IContains(id)).ToList();

            foreach (var actor in actors)
            {
                
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are forcing the relationship between actors and events to cascade they deleting for all children will be automatically...
otherwise i'll suppose you have a relation Key between both of them that your Actors had a `EventId` property.

```
Event eventObj = unitOfWork.Events.Get(id);

var actors = unitOfWork.Actors.where(x => x.EventId == id).ToList();

foreach(var actor in actors) {
    unitOfWork.Actors.remove(actor);
}

unitOfWork.Events.remove(eventObj);
```